# How to pass arguments to "Path" type parameters in Java?

Tags: java

I have tried the following Java code I found with the use of `BufferedReader` class to read a stream of text.

```
public void editTexts(Path inputFile) throws IOException{
    BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(inputFile)){
        // ----------                         
    }
}
```

As in this code, the parameter type is mentioned as `Path`. I have a problem with passing arguments into that.

I want to know how can I pass arguments to the `Path` parameter type?

Comment: What arguments do you want to pass?

Comment: I want to pass the argument to inputFile.

Comment: I have understood that, but **what kind of argument** do you want to pass there? A `Path` doesn't necessarily point to a file (directory or symbolic link are possible, too) and that file system object does not necessarily have to exist. Do you want to extend the path by a file name or a subdirectory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say, you have a `Path` pointing to a directory, let's say the root directory of a Windows machine.

You can create that `Path` like this:

```
Path rootPath = Paths.get("C:\\");
```

If you now want to *pass an argument* like a file name, then you can do this

```
String fileName = "some_file.txt";
Path filePath = rootPath.resolve(fileName);
```

To make sure everything is working correctly, print the absolute paths of both `Path`s

```
System.out.println("root path is " + rootPath.toAbsolutePath().toString());
System.out.println("path to the file in root is " + fileInRootPath.toAbsolutePath().toString());
```

You can perform checks on those `Path`s since having them created in memory doesn't necessarily mean the paths are correct and the file system objects are present.

```
// check if the path exists
if (Files.exists(filePath)) {
    // check if the path points to a regular file (not a directory or symbolic link)
    if (Files.isRegularFile(filePath)) {
        System.out.println(filePath.toAbsolutePath().toString() 
                + " exists and is a regular file");
    } else {
        System.out.println(filePath.toAbsolutePath().toString() 
                + " exists, but is not a regular file");
    }
} else {
    System.out.println(filePath.toAbsolutePath().toString()
            + " does not exist");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time! After I did all the changes you'd suggested it perfectly worked! And also can you further explain  _"I also suspect your code sample to not be using the Path inputFile…
Shouldn't bigFile in Files.newBufferedReader(bigFile) be replaced by inputFile"_

Comment: @UpaniK You're welcome! Would you mind to accept my answer?

Comment: Sure! @deHaar Can you explain to me why would I use `bigFile` instead of  `inputFile`. I guess this is because of best practices. I just want to make sure.

Comment: @UpaniK You shouldn't use `bigFile` because it is not the parameter but another variable (maybe defined somewhere before). In your code sample, both `Path`s used should be the same, the parameter... That's why I wrote that in my answer.

Comment: Okay. my bad.! Now I get it. I edited my question to prevent the cofussion. @deHaar Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Try [`Paths.get(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html#get-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-).

```
Path path = Paths.get("root", "sub", "subsub", "InterestingFile.txt");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. `Paths.get( )` did the job! Can you explain that the reason the path is separated by commas?